# ASP.NET GridView inside UpdatePanel won't get out of Edit Mode

Tags: asp.net, gridview, updatepanel

I have a pretty standard GridView with an SqlDataSource complete with SelectCommand/UpdateCommand/DeleteCommand.

I am utilising the Gridview's built-in commands for TemplateField'ed 's.

```
CommandName="Update"
CommandName="Edit"
CommandName="Cancel"
CommandName="Delete"
```

Everything works OK until I put the GridView inside an UpdatePanel. 
1. When I click on 'edit' it goes into edit mode but **won't get out of edit mode** when you click Cancel or Update.
2. When I click on 'delete' performs as it should, however, I won't be able to get into edit mode anymore even if I click 'edit'

What's the matter here?

Example code:

```
<asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
    <ContentTemplate>
        <div class="BoxFloat">
            <h4>Aliases</h4>
            <hr />
            <asp:SqlDataSource ID="sqlPersonAlias" runat="server" 
                ConnectionString="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString %>" 
                ProviderName="<%$ ConnectionStrings:myConnectionString.ProviderName %>" 
                DeleteCommand="DELETE FROM PersonAlias WHERE PersonAliasId=?PersonAliasId"
                UpdateCommand="UPDATE PersonAlias SET AliasName=?AliasName WHERE PersonAliasId=?PersonAliasId"
                SelectCommand="SELECT * FROM PersonAlias E INNER JOIN Person P ON P.PersonId=E.PersonId WHERE Username=?Username">
                <DeleteParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PersonAliasId" />
                </DeleteParameters>
                <UpdateParameters>
                    <asp:Parameter Name="PersonAliasId" />
                    <asp:Parameter Name="AliasName" />
                </UpdateParameters>
                <SelectParameters>
                    <asp:QueryStringParameter Name="Username" QueryStringField="Username" Type="String" />
                </SelectParameters>
            </asp:SqlDataSource>
            <asp:GridView ID="gridviewPersonAlias" runat="server"
                AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                DataKeyNames="PersonAliasId" 
                DataSourceID="sqlPersonAlias">
                <Columns>
                    <asp:TemplateField ShowHeader="False">
                        <EditItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imagebuttonCancel" ToolTip="Cancel" CommandName="Cancel" ImageUrl="~/images/cancel16.png" runat="server" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imagebuttonUpdate" ToolTip="Apply" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" CommandName="Update" ImageUrl="~/images/apply16.png" runat="server" />
                        </EditItemTemplate>
                        <ItemTemplate>
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imagebuttonDelete" ToolTip="Delete" OnClientClick="return confirm('Are you sure?');" CommandName="Delete" ImageUrl="~/images/delete16.png" runat="server" />
                            &nbsp;
                            <asp:ImageButton ID="imagebuttonEdit" ToolTip="Edit" CommandName="Edit" ImageUrl="~/images/edit16.png" runat="server" />
                        </ItemTemplate>
                    </asp:TemplateField>
                    <asp:BoundField DataField="AliasName" HeaderText="Alias" SortExpression="AliasName" />
                </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
            <hr />
            <asp:TextBox ID="textboxPersonAlias" runat="server" />
            <asp:Button ID="buttonPersonAliasAdd" runat="server" Text="Add" onclick="buttonPersonAliasAdd_Click" />
        </div>

    </ContentTemplate>
</asp:UpdatePanel>
```

When "Update" is clicked, the database gets updated. It seems that the problem is just with the client-side.

Note: I'm using "?" instead of "@" for the parameters because that SqlDataSource is using MySq instead of MSSQL (I love VS2010).

Comment: What behaviour do you see when you click the Cancel and Update buttons? Does the page post back? Does nothing happen at all? Try using FireBug or Chrome's developer tools to see what values are being posted to the server. Which browser are you using?

Comment: Nothing happens (on client-side, at least). The server-side methods seem to work (the database updates). I tested using Chrome and Firefox.

Comment: Maybe you have some other controls outside the updatepanel that affected, or maybe you have viewstate disabled ?

Answer (score 1):

I think what you need is full Postback or refresh the update Panel since it is most likely the gridview doesnt rebind
First try to put the sqldatasource outside the update panel. See if that works

Comment: The database seems to update properly though, when the update command is clicked. It's just that the GridView won't render out of EditItemTemplate and go back ti ItemTemplate

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem in my project, and solved it.

here is my solution:

```
protected void gvPayments_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
{
  //here is the edit code
  //......
  //at the end add these lines:
  gvPayments.EditIndex = -1;
  gvPayments.DataBind();
  e.Cancel = true;
}
```